# vim-go doesn't find need libraries

Tags: go, vim, settings, neovim

I install neovim and bigin to setup. I install vim-go and after execute :GoInstallBinaries, and all need libraries installed to my GOPATH, all good. But result command in vim `:GoDef, :GoDoc:` - give me msg:

```
vim-go: /bin/sh: 1: guru: not found
vim-go: /bin/sh: 1: gogetdoc: not found
```

I use zsh, not standart shell(zsh default shell), i try write `set shell=$SHELL` and `set shell=/bin/zsh` in my vimrc and init.vim file - no 
effect and i set correct path in .bashrc to my GOPATH.
I think problem with vim-go which use /bin/sh, may by. Any ideas? And very strange vim-go install libraries to GOPATH, but doesэt find them there
Thank you!

Comment: Did you install `guru` and `gogetdoc`?

Comment: Yes. vim-go after start command :GoInstallBinaries - install all binaries to GOPATH/bin and i see https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/32ae8640716530bd55062379177da51efb37dfd2/autoload/go/util.vim#L140 library how i understand use /bin/sh by default

Answer (score 0):

> i set correct path in .bashrc to my GOPATH.

`zsh` doesn't use .bashrc use `.zshrc` instead.

Comment: i know, and i use zsh. But problem, why vim-go write: vim-go: /bin/sh: 1: guru: not found - why /bin/sh?????

Comment: maybe the underlying script uses #!/bin/sh shebang.

Answer (score 0):

Be a long time to laugh, but I had to restart the computer ......frenzy....